# Linq to get elements in a list (parent) where a condition is satisfied on property of an object in a child list?

Tags: linq

I was wondering if someone could help me in generating a linq query for the following scenario.

Here are the classes with the relevant properties:

```
public class Employee 
{
    IList<Employee> DirectReports { get; set;}
    IList<BonusPlan> BonusPlans { get; set;}

    BonusPlanTemplate BonusPlanTemplate { get; set;}
}

public class BonusPlan
{
    FiscalPeriod FiscalPeriod { get; set; }
    Employee Employee { get; set;}
}
```

I'm trying to create a method:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> GetDirectReportsWithoutBonusPlansCreatedForFiscalPeriod(FiscalPeriod fiscalPeriod)
```

So basically I have this to get the directreports with bonus plans for a particular fiscal period:

```
var query = from dr in DirectReports
            from bp in dr.BonusPlans
            where bp.Employee.BonusPlanTemplate != BonusPlanTemplate.Empty && 
              bp.FiscalPeriod==fiscalPeriod
            select dr;

IList<Employee> directReportsWithBonusPlansCreated = query.ToList();
```

Then I get all of the DirectReports that should have bonus plans setup (indicated by having a BonusPlanTemplate assigned) that aren't in the list from the previous query.

```
var query2 = from dr in DirectReports
             where dr.BonusPlanTemplate != BonusPlanTemplate.Empty &&
                !directReportsWithBonusPlansCreated.Contains(dr)
             select dr;
```

This produces the correct results but it seems like there must be another way.  I'm not sure if I need to do this in two steps.  Can someone please help me to combine these two linq queries and possibly make it more efficient.  I have relatively little experience with Linq.

Comment: Your first query will give duplicates if any direct reports have multiple bonus plans for a single period... is that deliberate?

Comment: Thank you for that comment.  In the future there will be a status field where there can only be one bonus plan for an employee with a "created" status at a time.  But you're right.  As it is, I will get duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need the first query for any other reason? If not, it's pretty easy:

```
var query = from dr in DirectReports
            where dr.BonusPlanTemplate != BonusPlanTemplate.Empty
               && !dr.BonusPlans.Any(bp => bp.FiscalPeriod == fiscalPeriod)
            select dr;
```

You could make your life easier use an extra method in `Employee`:

```
public bool HasBonusPlanForPeriod(FiscalPeriod period)
{
    return BonusPlans.Any(bp => bp.FiscalPeriod == fiscalPeriod);
}
```

Then your original first query becomes:

```
var query = from dr in DirectReports
            where dr.BonusPlanTemplate != BonusPlanTemplate.Empty && 
                  dr.HasBonusPlanForPeriod(fiscalPeriod)
            select dr;

IList<Employee> directReportsWithBonusPlansCreated = query.ToList();
```

and the second query becomes:

```
var query = from dr in DirectReports
            where dr.BonusPlanTemplate != BonusPlanTemplate.Empty && 
                  !dr.HasBonusPlanForPeriod(fiscalPeriod)
            select dr;

IList<Employee> directReportsWithBonusPlansCreated = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I really didn't need the first query for anything other than doing set subtraction, due to my lack of knowledge of how to do a "not in" equivalent expession in Linq.  Your solution still makes my unit tests pass.  Thanks Jon!

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky one...first I thought "Oh it's an outer join...use DefaultIfEmpty". Then I realized you were doing a select many (that's what the two from clauses boil down to). So I did a search for DefaultIfEmpty combined with SelectMany and [came up with this gem](https://www.re-motion.org/blogs/mix/2010/09/04/the-defaultifempty-linq-query-operator). Applied to your scenario we get

```
var query = 
  from dr in DirectReports              
  from bp in dr.BonusPlans.DefaultIfEmpty()

  where dr.BonusPlanTemplate != BonusPlanTemplate.Empty && 
  bp.FiscalPeriod==fiscalPeriod &&
  bp==null
  select dr;
```

See if that works for you.